# azure bicep template with module doing a union of web slot config appsettings

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment, azure-bicep

I am trying to get a list of my current sites/slot app config and then combining it with a union so I don't overwrite the current deployed configuration.  I am able to do this with the sites config but cannot with the deploy slot.

Here is an example of my **working** web sites
in **main.bicep**

```
resource sites_web_name 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
       parameters here(irrelevant for excercise)
}
```

```
module web_appsettings_config './appsettings.bicep' = {
  name: 'webAppSettings'
  params: {
  //this gets a list of the current app settings for the web site resource
    currentAppSettings: list('${sites_web_name.id}/config/appsettings', '2021-02-01').properties
    appSettings: {
      'Config1': 'confighere'
      'Config2': 'config2here'
      'Config3': 'config3here'
    }
    name: '${sites_web_name.name}/appsettings'
  }
}
```

**appsettings.bicep**

```
param currentAppSettings object
param appSettings object
param name string

resource siteConfig 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-02-01' = {
  name: name
  properties: union(currentAppSettings, appSettings)
}
```

The above is taking the current app settings deployed, not deleting/overwriting them if the new ones aren't specified in the template.

Now the problem trying to get sites/slot

**main.bicep**

```
resource sites_web_slots_name 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2021-02-01' = {
    parameters here(irrelevant for excercise)
}
```

```
module web_staging_appsettings_config './slotappsettings.bicep' = {
  name: 'webStagingAppSettings'
  params: {
  //this gets a list of the current app settings for the web slot resource
    currentAppSettings: list('${sites_web_slots_name.id}/slots/config/appsettings', '2021-02-01').properties
    appSettings: {
      'Config1': 'confighere'
      'Config2': 'config2here'
      'Config3': 'config3here'
    }
    name: '${sites_web_slots_name.name}/appsettings'
  }
}
```

even made a separate module, **slotappsettings.bicep**

```
param currentAppSettings object
param appSettings object
param name string

resource siteSlotConfig 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config@2021-02-01' = {
  name: name
  properties: union(currentAppSettings, appSettings)
}
```

The error I am getting for the slots failure is not helpful at all:

ERROR: {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"NotFound","message":"{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "InvalidResourceNamespace",\r\n    "message": "The resource namespace 'subscriptions' is invalid."\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}

I also don't get any deployment failure messages in the azure portal.
Here is the documentation for the api versions I'm using:

sites/config/appsettings:

[sites/config-appsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2021-02-01/sites/config-appsettings?tabs=bicep)

```
resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'appsettings'
  kind: 'string'
  parent: resourceSymbolicName
  properties: {}
}
```

sites/slots/config/appsettings:

[sites/slots/config-appsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2021-02-01/sites/slots/config-appsettings?tabs=bicep)

```
resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'appsettings'
  kind: 'string'
  parent: resourceSymbolicName
  properties: {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo while calling the `list` function for the slot settings:

You have `/slots/config/appsettings` but it should only be `/config/appsettings` because the `/slots` segment is already included in the resource id of the slot (`sites_web_slots_name.id`)

Comment: That is a bit embarrassing... that worked, I did have to change the params name as well after to: name: '${sites_web_name.name}/${sites_web_slots_name.name}/appsettings' Thanks for the second set of eyes, I've been in bicep for too long now..

Comment: No worries, we all do this kind of typo, hopefully you didn't loose too much time on that  :-)